# Reporting on inactive picklist values

Tags: classic

i want to pull reports and use an old pick list value that is now inactive. How can i achieve this.
Can i report on an inactive picklist value? 
Is it possible at all.

Comment: will the picklist value still be available and populate into exixsting report?

Comment: Use SOQL instead